Determine the condition of $\lambda$ so that the given linear programing problem has infinitely many optimal solutions
I'm having the following linear programming problem:

$f = 2x_1 + 4x_2 + \lambda x_3 \text{( to max )} \text{ with constraints  } x_i \ge 0\, \forall i = 1,2,3,4$ and
$\left\{\begin{aligned}{}
         & x_1 + 3x_2 + x_4 =4\\
         & 2x_1 + x_2 + x_3 =3 \\
         & x_2 - 3x_4 \le 3
    \end{aligned}
    \right.$
Find $\lambda$ so that the given linear programing problem has infinitely optimal solutions.

I try to use simplex to do directly with that, but get 3 cases of $\lambda$ ($\ge 4$, $\ge 1$, $0$) to have optimal plan (like max = 3$\lambda$), but then realized it wasn't a good way.
Is there anyway to solve that, like using duality problem?

It would take a bit more looking at your work to see what exactly happens, but if you are getting three different basic solutions depending on whether $\lambda \le 1$, $1 < \lambda \le 4$, or $\lambda >4$, then I would look at the boundary points $\lambda=1$ and $\lambda=4$ to see if you get infinitely many solutions there! (My approach to this problem would be exactly to solve the LP in terms of $\lambda$ to find where these boundary points are, though there are easier and harder ways to do that.)

(In my work, comparing $\lambda$ to $1$ didn't come up, though, so double-check that you're performing the simplex method correctly.)

The simplex method is the most reasonable way to go here, but if you're not used to performing it with a parameter, it takes some practice.
Here is what I would do to determine the full effect of $\lambda$ on the LP:
Step 1. Solve the LP while treating $\lambda$ as $-\infty$: that is, smaller than anything else we compare it to. In this particular LP, that has the effect of making sure $x_3$ is nonbasic.
Adding $s$ as a slack variable for the third constraint, I get the following optimal dictionary* here:
\begin{align}
   f &= 6 + \left(\lambda - \frac25\right) x_3 - \frac65 x_4 \\
   x_1 &= 1 - \frac35 x_3 + \frac15 x_4 \\
   x_2 &= 1 + \frac15 x_3 - \frac25 x_4 \\
   s &= 2 - \frac15 x_3 + \frac{17}{5} x_4
\end{align}
Step 2. Increase $\lambda$ just enough to matter. Here, we see that the solution above remains optimal (all reduced costs remain nonpositive) as long as $\lambda \le \frac25$. So treat $\lambda$ as $\frac25 + \epsilon$: bigger than $\frac25$, but smaller than the next largest thing we'll have to compare it to.
This gives us another pivoting step to do, after which we'll reach another optimal dictionary:
\begin{align}
   f &= \frac13(16+5\lambda) + \frac13(2-5\lambda)x_1 + \frac13(\lambda-4)x_4 \\
   x_2 &= \frac43 - \frac13 x_1 - \frac13 x_4 \\
   x_3 &= \frac53 - \frac53x_1 + \frac13 x_4 \\
   s &= \frac53 + \frac13 x_1 + \frac{10}3 x_4
\end{align}
Step 3. Keep going like this. The new dictionary remains optimal when $\frac25 \le \lambda \le 4$, so we increase $\lambda$ to $4+\epsilon$ and see what happens, getting a new optimal dictionary:
\begin{align}
   f &= 3\lambda + (2-2\lambda)x_1 + (4-\lambda)x_2 \\
   x_3 &= 3 - 2x_1 - x_2 \\
   x_4 &= 4 - x_1 - 3x_2 \\
   s &= 15 - 3x_1 - 10x_2
\end{align}
We see that this dictionary is optimal for all $\lambda \ge 4$, so nothing changes when we increase $\lambda$ any further.
Summary. What we've learned from the above is that there are three possible optimal basic solutions depending on $\lambda$:

$(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (1,1,0,0)$ is optimal with objective value $6$ as long as $\lambda \le \frac25$;
$(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (0, \frac43, \frac53, 0)$ is optimal with objective value $\frac13(16+5\lambda)$ as long as $\frac25 \le \lambda \le 4$;
$(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (0,0,3,4)$ is optimal with objective value $3\lambda$ as long as $\lambda \ge 4$.

This should be enough to determine the values of $\lambda$ where infinitely many optimal solutions exist, and even parameterize the line segment of optimal solutions in each case.

* I used dictionaries in this answer, though I realize many people use tableaux. I figure this is better for explaining the simplex method, since a dictionary is straightforward to translate to the tableau of your choice: solve each equation for the RHS you want, and put the coefficients in a grid. Meanwhile, if you're not familiar with the details of a particular tableau notation, you have to solve a logic puzzle to convert it to a dictionary or even just to switch to a different style of tableau.
